# How to use JNLP to pass command line arguments to the application?

Tags: java, arguments, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a JNLP package for my application.
Now I have the need to pass command line arguments to my application.
How do I extend my JNLP file to list the command line arguments?

For instance, I need to say `java main.class arg1 arg2` and the `arg1` and `arg2` need to be mentioned as part of JNLP file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look to the description of the [`application-desc` Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#application_desc) for further details of the `argument` element.

> The `application` element indicates that the JNLP file is launching an application (as opposed to an applet). ..
>
> *Arguments can be specified to the application by including one or more nested `argument` elements.*
>  For example:

```xml
  <application-desc main-class="Main">
    <argument>arg1</argument>
    <argument>arg2</argument>
  </application-desc>
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass arguments to installer-desc tags for installation JNLP files (which will not have application-desc)?

Comment: @plusjeff  You should ask that as a separate question.